# Http Response from Kafka Consumer

Tags: api, http, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Would it be possible to create a server that publishes a client's request to Kafka's topic, and the Consumer that is subscribed to the topic will respond directly to the client?

`client -> server -> kafka -> consumer -> client`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for an HTTP bridge, able to bridge the Apache Kafka protocol over HTTP.
I would suggest to take a look at the Strimzi HTTP - Kafka bridge here: https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-bridge
It's open source and Apache 2.0 licensed. It's not just when you have Kafka running on Kubernetes via the Strimzi project but even if you have a bare metal Kafka installation. Details on the official documentation: https://strimzi.io/docs/bridge/latest/
Another one is the Confluent REST proxy here: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest
Still open source but with a custom Confluent Community License. Official documentation https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am not looking for a bridge I will implement the connection myself. I want to know how (if possible) to return a response from the consumer to the client without going through the server (the publisher).

Comment: At this point you should clarify what client (on the left side) is, what server is, what client (on the right side) is. I assume it's HTTP client -> HTTP server -> kafka -> Kafka consumer -> client (??? what kind of client is this)? And what kind of response are you looking for?

Comment: Yes, it is like this I assume it's HTTP client -> HTTP server -> kafka -> Kafka consumer -> client. And the client Will be React. I am expecting to get from the server a JWT.

Comment: But your question is still not clear. You should elaborate more.